# how to pass plot arguments when using split for multivariate point process

Tags: spatstat

To learn some plotting in spatstat, I am trying to plot database mucosa using the split function to create a *multivariate* plot. I get two different subplots of mucosa, but by default they both have the same symbology.

```
library(spatstat)    
plot(split(mucosa))
```

Now in the two subplots, I would like to customise each subplot in terms of colour, size, shape etc. How can I do this? please advice.

I tried to pass pch and cex and col as a vector of two elements (because I know it is two types), but I get error

```
plot(split(mucosa), pch=c(19,3))
Error in symbolmap(..., chars = chars, cols = cols) : 
  Argument ‘pch’ is neither a function nor a constant
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the argument `chars` instead of `pch` to specify several plotting characters.

In the call to `split`, you need to specify the argument `un=FALSE` which ensures that each of the split point patterns retains its original mark information (i.e. the type of each point).

So you need

```
plot(split(mucosa, un=FALSE), chars=c(19,3))
```

Comment: Thank you. This answers my question.

Answer (score 1):

It seems untraditional to plot the types with different plotting characters when they are split into different panels. Why do you want to do that?

If you plot them in the same single plot you can just do as you suggest:

```
plot(mucosa, pch = c(19, 3))
```

And here you can add `cols`, `cex`, ...

However, if you first split the point pattern the more complicated `plot.listof` is called and you can look at that help file for details. Also if you look at our book Baddeley, Rubak and Turner (2015) you may find multi-panel plots which may inspire you. On the companion website for the book you can find code to generate all the figures of the book (requires a bit of searching though).

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I just wanted to have a distinct display, no strong technical reason for plotting different characters. But thank you for mentioning about the companion site. Please see, figurelayout.R is missing on that site. May be you can upload it.